How to add an input checkbox that will only show the FIRST label
I want to add an input checkbox to either only show a label on the first candle when the RSI goes extreme and crosses the input level (when checked ON) or shows them on every candle in the extreme zone (when checked off).
I have the following code so far that shows the labels on every candle when extreme.
UPDATE: Thanks to Vitruvius, I was able to get the oversold labels working with the var function but when I try that on the overbought it now shows a label  on every candle for current RSI even if not in the overbought level. Updated code below:
RSIPeriod = input.int(14, title = 'RSI Period', step = 1, minval = 1)
RSISource = input(title = 'RSI Source', defval = close)

OS = input.int(30, title = 'Oversold Level', maxval = 100, minval = 1, step = 1)
OB = input.int(70, title = 'Overbought Level', maxval = 100, minval = 1, step = 1)

RSI = ta.rsi(RSISource, RSIPeriod)

bool IsOS = false
bool IsOB = false

in_show_first = input.bool(false, "Show only the first label")

var is_os_first_lbl_created = false
var is_ob_first_lbl_created = false

if RSI <= OS
   if (in_show_first and not is_os_first_lbl_created)
       label lup1 = label.new(bar_index, na, str.tostring(int(RSI)), color = color.lime, textcolor = color.black, style = label.style_label_up, size = size.small, yloc = yloc.belowbar)
       is_os_first_lbl_created := true
   else
       label lup1 = label.new(bar_index, na, str.tostring(int(RSI)), color = color.lime, textcolor = color.black, style = label.style_label_up, size = size.small, yloc = yloc.belowbar)
       
   IsOS := true

if RSI >= OB
   if (in_show_first and not is_ob_first_lbl_created)
       label lup2 = label.new(bar_index, na, str.tostring(int(RSI)), color = color.red, textcolor = color.white, style = label.style_label_down, size = size.small, yloc = yloc.abovebar)
       is_ob_first_lbl_created := true
   else
       label lup2 = label.new(bar_index, na, str.tostring(int(RSI)), color = color.red, textcolor = color.white, style = label.style_label_down, size = size.small, yloc = yloc.abovebar)
       
   IsOB := true



Just add a var flag to see if you have already created the label or not.
var is_os_first_lbl_created = false
var is_ob_first_lbl_created = false

if RSI <= OS
    if (in_show_first)
        if (not is_os_first_lbl_created)
            label lup1 = label.new(bar_index, na, str.tostring(int(RSI)), color = color.lime, textcolor = color.black, style = label.style_label_up, size = size.small, yloc = yloc.belowbar)
            is_os_first_lbl_created := true
    else
        label lup1 = label.new(bar_index, na, str.tostring(int(RSI)), color = color.lime, textcolor = color.black, style = label.style_label_up, size = size.small, yloc = yloc.belowbar)
       
    IsOS := true

if RSI >= OB
    if (in_show_first)
        if(not is_ob_first_lbl_created)
            label lup2 = label.new(bar_index, na, str.tostring(int(RSI)), color = color.red, textcolor = color.white, style = label.style_label_down, size = size.small, yloc = yloc.abovebar)
            is_ob_first_lbl_created := true
    else
        label lup2 = label.new(bar_index, na, str.tostring(int(RSI)), color = color.red, textcolor = color.white, style = label.style_label_down, size = size.small, yloc = yloc.abovebar)
       
    IsOB := true


Thanks! I tried the same for the overbought but it's now showing labels for every RSI even if not overbought. I updated the code in the original post. What did I do wrong?

It should only show the first one, no?

Correct it should but it seems to still be showing multiples in a row: imgur.com/a/xTtFpX3

Someone suggested using the barsince function set to 1 but I'm not really familiar with it, thoughts on that route?

I'm just trying to understand your requirements. If you only want the FIRST label, then you will only have two labels on your chart, right?

Actually, my bad. There is a logic error in the code. Updated the code now. Please check.
